# Remove default groupings in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

In order to remove the default groupings generated by ggplot2 for (say) a `geom_line` plot, I have always set the `group` aesthetic to an integer constant with**in** `aes(...)`.

However, given that I am simply mapping `group` to a constant... **Why does it need to be set within `aes(...)` and cannot be outside?**

For example, the following code generates a single continuous line with coloured segments:

```
library (ggplot2)

dfSomeData <-
  data.frame(
    x = 1L:9L,
    y = 1L,
    colour = c(rep('red', 3L), rep('blue', 3L), rep('green', 3L))
  )

ggplot(dfSomeData, aes(x = x, y = y, colour = colour, group = 1L)) +
  geom_line()
```

Yet, the following does not:

```
ggplot(dfSomeData, aes(x = x, y = y, colour = colour), group = 1L) +
  geom_line()
```

There's clearly a subtlety here that I am missing!

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question. According to the docs `group` outside an `aes` isn't used (ggplot version 2_3.3.3)

Comment: Ah ok... Can you provide a link? I wasn't aware that 'group' outside 'aes' would be ignored. Thanks!

Comment: just type in `?ggplot` in an R prompt to get the doc, it should say near the top what all the args do (and don't do)